# How to solve this Scala/Play compilation error (wrong type being returned)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, compiler-errors, playframework-2.3

I am trying to write a JSON deserializer that plugs into Play Framework controllers, in lieu of the standard Play JSON library. The rationale is to be able to use Jackson directly. I have been able to come up with a pluggable deserializer, thanks to [a recipe by Maarten Winkels](http://blog.xebia.com/2012/07/22/play-body-parsing-with-jerkson/), but I am stuck due to a compilation error that I just don't understand (disclaimer: I am a Scala novice).

The compilation error stems from the fact that apparently a branch of `JsonObjectParser.apply` tries to return an instance of `Object`, whereas it should be `Result`. I don't understand why this is happening though. My question is, how do I solve this error?

## Compilation Error

The compilation error looks like this:

```
/Users/arve/Projects/test/JsonObjectParser.scala:26: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Object
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]         case Left((r, in)) => Done(Left(r), El(in))
```

## JsonObjectParser.scala

This is the source code in question:

```
import java.io.{ByteArrayInputStream, InputStream}

import play.api.Play
import play.api.libs.iteratee.Input._
import play.api.libs.iteratee._
import play.api.mvc._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class JsonObjectParser[A: Manifest](deserializer: (InputStream) => A) extends BodyParser[A] {
  val JsonMaxLength = 4096

  def apply(request: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, A]] = {
    Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](JsonMaxLength).apply(Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map { bytes =>
      scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[A].either {
        deserializer(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
      }.left.map { e =>
        (Play.maybeApplication.map(_.global.onBadRequest(request, "Invalid Json")).getOrElse(
          Results.BadRequest), bytes)
      }
    }).flatMap(Iteratee.eofOrElse(Results.EntityTooLarge))
      .flatMap {
      case Left(b) => Done(Left(b), Empty)
      case Right(it) => it.flatMap {
        // Won't compile
        case Left((r, in)) => Done(Left(r), El(in))
        case Right(a) => Done(Right(a), Empty)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Alternatively,

If you guys know of a better way to plug a custom JSON deserializer into Play, on top of Jackson, that would be acceptable too. That is what I'm trying to do here after all.

Comment: `case Left((r, in)) => Done(Left(r), El(in))` doesn't really make sense - if there was any remaining input, the `case Left(b)` branch immediately above would have been followed. I think what you might want is `case Left(r) => Done(Left(r), Empty)`. However, I think if you use `transform` instead of `apply` you can do away with the second `flatMap` completely.

Comment: @wingedsubmariner Want to try typing up an answer with complete code? I could use some hand holding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `eofOrElse` `Iteratee` wraps the result  of the previous `Iteratee` into an `Either`. Because the result of the previous Iteratee was already an `Either`, you end up with something like `Either[Result, Either[Result, A]]`. A call to `joinRight` can transform this into the `Either[Result, A]` we require. Also `_.global.onBadRequest(request, "Invalid Json")` returns a `Future[SimpleResult]`, not a `SimpleResult` - I've removed that code.

Below I've applied those fixes as well as simplified the tuple returned from `.left.map` call and also used `transform` instead of `apply` in order to do away with the last `flatMap`.

```
class JsonObjectParser[A: Manifest](deserializer: (InputStream) => A) extends BodyParser[A] {
  val JsonMaxLength = 4096

  def apply(request: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[SimpleResult, A]] = {
    Traversable.takeUpTo[Array[Byte]](JsonMaxLength).transform {
      Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().map { bytes =>
        scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch[A].either {
          deserializer(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes))
        }.left.map { _ =>
          Results.BadRequest
        }
      }
    }.flatMap(Iteratee.eofOrElse(Results.EntityTooLarge)).map(_.joinRight)
  }
}
```

Comment: This fails with another error: `JsonObjectParser.scala:25: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],Either[play.api.mvc.Results.Status,Serializable with Product with scala.util.Either[Object,A]]]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee[Array[Byte],Either[play.api.mvc.Result,A]]
[error]     }.flatMap(Iteratee.eofOrElse(Results.EntityTooLarge))`

Comment: Currently fails with `JsonObjectParser.scala:25: Cannot prove that Serializable with Product with scala.util.Either[Object,A] <:< scala.util.Either[play.api.mvc.Results.Status,C].
[error]     }.flatMap(Iteratee.eofOrElse(Results.EntityTooLarge)).map(_.joinRight)`

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
case Left(b) => Done(Left(b), Empty)
```

Is calling `Done` with `Left(b)` where `b` is of type `play.api.mvc.Results.Status`. This sets the expectation for the type of the iteratee that will be returned by the enclosing `flatMap`.

On this line:

```
case Left((r, in)) => Done(Left(r), El(in))
```

`Done` is being called with `Left(r)` where `r` is of type `Object`, resulting in an iteratee of a different type than the `case Left` branch is returning.

Changing that line to:

```
case Left((r: Result, in)) => Done(Left(r), El(in))
```

produces an iteratee of the same type as the previous, avoiding the compile error.

Without digging deep in the algorithm, it can't be told if that is the appropriate change, but the more general answer is that all code branches must return compatible types.

As a tip, using the Scala plugin for Eclipse you can hover the mouse over a variable to see its type. Sometimes, dividing the code in chunks assigned to explicitly typed variables can also make it clearer which types are being dealth with, at the expense of making the code more verbose.

Comment: Thanks, but after making your change it breaks with another error: `method apply has incompatible type
[error]   def apply(request: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Either[Result, A]] = {`

Comment: That's an additional error. The statement with `Play.maybeApplication.map` is returning `Product with Serializable with scala.util.Either[(Object, Array[Byte]),A]` instead of just `Either[(Object, Array[Byte]),A]`. There are more errors such as `match may not be exhaustive`. Stack Overflow is not a good fit for custom code debugging, but following the process explained in my answer should enable you to do that.